# Get all sms conversation a particular number,

Tags: java, android

**It's Query of getting all inbox msg of particular number
but how i can get conversation or sent items with it**

```
 private void showContacts(String number) {

    ArrayList<Bean_Chat> arrayList=new ArrayList();


    String[] phoneNumber = new String[] { number };
    ContentResolver contentResolver =getContentResolver();
    Cursor smsInboxCursor = contentResolver.query((Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox")), new String[]{}, "address=?", phoneNumber, null);

    int indexBody = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("body");


    if (indexBody < 0 || !smsInboxCursor.moveToFirst()) return;
    adapter=null;
    do {

        String inbox= smsInboxCursor.getString(indexBody) + "\n";

        arrayList.add(new Bean_Chat("",inbox));
    } while (smsInboxCursor.moveToNext());
```